# Why are static blocks/static variables in super class initialized before main?

Tags: java, static-initialization

```
public class sup {
    static {
        System.out.print("In Sup  ");
    }
}


public class sub extends sup {
    static {
        System.out.print("In Sub");
    }
}

final public class test extends sub {
    static int a = 10;

    static {
        System.out.print("  In test" + a);
    }

    {
        System.out.print("  In test" + a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Output:

```
In Sup  In Sub  In test10
```

But here I am not creating object. The JVM should call the main method which is static and initialize the main class only. So it should give output `In test10`.

Could anyone please explain why I'm getting different output?

Comment: When you run a `Class` with a `main` method, the JVM will make an attempt to load the class. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` initializer blocks are called when the class loader loads a class. In a nutshell, the order of execution here is as follows:

1. Attempt to load `test`, see it depends on `sub`
2. Attempt to load `sub`, see it depends on `sup`
3. Attempt to load `sup`
4. `sup` is loaded, and its `static` block prints `"In Sup"`
5. `sub`'s loading is resumed, and its `static` block prints `"In Sub"`
6. `test`'s loading is resumed, and `a` is initialized to `10`.
7. `test`'s `static` block is executed and prints `" In test10"`
8. `test`'s `main` function is executed, and does nothing, since it's empty.

Comment: I think the OP is asking *What triggers the initialization process* rather than *What are the steps in the initialization process*.

Comment: @CKing I thought I started out with explaining this "static initializer blocks are called when the class loader loads a class." Could you point out how you think this explanation is lacking? I'd love to improve my answer if possible.

Comment: The OP says *But here I am not creating object*. It is an indication that the OP thinks that class loading is triggered only when you create an instance of a class. When you say *static initializer blocks are called when the class loader loads a class*, you don't explain what triggers the class loader to load the class.

Comment: Thanks @mureinik i just tried and i am able to understand complete flow. I was thinking JVM will create object of main and thats why all super classes had been initiated. Thanks for your explanation. really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Static blocks are executed *before* `main` method. Since `test extends sub` and `sub extends sup`, the static block of `sup` will be executed, then the static block of `sub` and finally the static block of `test`.

See the [JLS - 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) for detailed explanation:

```
class Super {
    static { System.out.print("Super "); }
}
class One {
    static { System.out.print("One "); }
}
class Two extends Super {
    static { System.out.print("Two "); }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        One o = null;
        Two t = new Two();
        System.out.println((Object)o == (Object)t);
    }
}
```

This example demonstrates the order of execution, the output would be

```
Super Two false
```

Comment: Note that `class one ` is not loaded because the compiler doesn't pass this value (statement) to the JVM as part of metadata..

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will load a class when the class is run regardless of whether you create an instance of the class or not.

This is clearly specified in [Section 12.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) of the Java language specification.

> ```
> java Test reboot Bob Dot Enzo
> ```
>
> The initial attempt to execute the method main of class Test discovers that the class Test is not loaded - that is, that the Java Virtual Machine does not currently contain a binary representation for this class. The Java Virtual Machine then uses a class loader to attempt to find such a binary representation

Answer (score 0):

*here i am not creating object.*. It is not about creation of objects. Even before you create an object, the class and its related dependencies have to be loaded / initialized. Classes can get loaded when you access `static methods` present in them (`main` is `static`). Since your `test` class depends on `sub` and `sub` depends on `sup`, the JVM loads them in the order sup --> sub --> test so that the dependencies for the class 'test' are resolved. Unless this is done, your 'test' cannot use fields / methods of its super classes.

Answer (score 0):

static block/variable/methods are not inheritable as they belong to class not object.

The reason why you are getting this output is, JVM needs to load the main class's complete hierarchy to execute the main method (parent class then child).

If you remove the inheritance from test class, you would get only 'In test10'.